# Select One menu items show ItemValue instead of ItemLabel

Tags: jsf

I need to localize the items in a `selectOneMenu`. But, instead of taking the variables' labels its showing the value of the item.
The backing bean contains the following:

```
private static final String[] UPGRADE = { "Standard", "Privilege", "Basic" };
private static final String[] UPGRADE_LABELS = {Resource.getMessage("lblStandard"), Resource.getMessage("lblPrivilege"), Resource.getMessage("lblBasic")};

for(int i = 0;i<UPGRADE.length;i++) {
    String value = UPGRADE[i];
    String label = UPGRADE_LABELS[i];
    item = new SelectItem(value, label);
    allLevelStatus.add(item);
}
```

And here's the xhtml part:

```
<h:selectOneMenu style="width:125px; font-size:12px;" id="selectstatusTypePro"
                 value="#{startNotificationBean.levelStatus}" disabled="#{startNotificationBean.editUpdate}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['lblAny']}" itemValue="Any" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{startNotificationBean.allLevelStatus}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: In other words, you have accidentally swapped `UPGRADE` and `UPGRADE_LABELS`? JSF is merely presenting the model you give to it.

Comment: And how is `allLevelStatus` declared?